# Same image shown multiple times. Change only one at a time using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image of a gray star or blue star shown multiple times on the page. When I click on the gray star, it should change to blue. And when I click on the blue star, it should change to gray. Right now, when I click on one star, it changes all of them. How do I only change one image at a time?

This is in my root.html.erb

```
<img class="star-pic" src="/assets/star-gray.png">
```

This is in my javascript/application.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function changeStar(){
    if($(".star-pic").attr("src") == "/assets/star-gray.png"){
      $(".star-pic").attr("src", "/assets/star-blue.png")
    }
    else{
      $(".star-pic").attr("src", "/assets/star-gray.png")
    }
  }

  $(".star-pic").on("click", changeStar)

})
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need to post all the relevant HTML, but `$(".star-pic").on("click", changeStar)` adds a `click` callback to **all** elements with a class of `star-pic`, so that's why clicking any of them causes the code to run.

Comment: @ScottMarcus that's not the reason. The reason is because the selector is being used in the handler rather than just `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your function `changeStar()` you are selecting all the images when any image is clicked and changing all of them as a result. Using `$(this)` selects the element that was clicked and changes it only.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function changeStar() {
    if ($(this).attr("src") == "/assets/star-gray.png") {
      $(this).attr("src", "/assets/star-blue.png")
    } else {
      $(this).attr("src", "/assets/star-gray.png")
    }
  }

  $(".star-pic").on("click", changeStar)
})
```

Comment: This answer is correct but it can be improved... may I?

Comment: I wasn't talking about formatting or explanation. If you save `var $this = $(this)` at the top of `changeStar()`, and use `$this` instead of `$(this)` in the rest of the function, that saves a _lot_ of overhead and improves performance by initializing the jQuery object only once.

Comment: Oh yeah! But I wanted the answer to be more self-explanatory. A beginner might get confused between $this and $(this). By the way, does it affect performance that much? If yes, then we should simply use vanilla JS then :)

Comment: @Sid24 constructing a jQuery object invokes a lot of overhead, but if you use it effectively like my suggestion states, the performance drop is minimal enough to be worth the functionality that jQuery gives you.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting up your click event such that all `.star-pic` elements have their style modified when any are clicked because of this:

```
$(".star-pic").attr("src", "/assets/star-blue.png")
```

This changes the `src` attribute for all members of the JQuery wrapped set.

You only want to modify the one that was clicked so you should be writing:

```
$(this).attr("src", "/assets/star-blue.png")
```

to only affect the one that was clicked.

But, beyond that, your code can be dramatically reduced and the solution hugely simplified if you get rid of the `img` elements completely and just use `div` (or `span`) elements that have their `background-image` set via membership in a CSS class. Then, all you have to do it toggle that class membership.

```js
$(function(){
  function changeStar(){
    // Use $(this) to get a reference to just the element being clicked as a JQuery object
    // Simply toggle the use of the greyStar class to toggle the image shown
    $(this).toggleClass("greyStar");
  }

  $(".star-pic").on("click", changeStar)
});
```

```css
.star-pic {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-size:cover;
  /* All elements default to showing a blue star */
  background-image:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/98/Human-emblem-star-blue-128.png");
  display:inline-block;
}

/* But some elements are coded in the HTML to override blue and show grey from the start */
.greyStar {
  background-image:url("http://www.dyson.com/airtreatment/humidifiers/am10/am10-white-silver/medialibrary/Reviews/Grey-star.ashx");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="star-pic greyStar"></span>
<span class="star-pic"></span>
<span class="star-pic greyStar"></span>
<span class="star-pic"></span>
<span class="star-pic greyStar"></span>
<span class="star-pic"></span>
```

Comment: @PatrickRoberts This was done so that CSS classes can be used instead of swapping `src` on images.

Comment: Yes but as shown in the demo, if you have a `src`, that renders on top of `background-image`, so it changes nothing unless you change the `src`. If you want to go with CSS classes, just use a `<div>` or something, this is not a good practice with `<img>`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts See the CSS. The `url` property of the `background-image` changes as class membership changes.

Comment: Use URLs that resolve to actual images and you will see that the `border` will be the only visible change.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That's not true. I'm just trying to find a good blue star image to use in this example, but you can see that the image does change.

Comment: Fair enough... I can't help but wonder how (in)compatible this is though, not to mention there's literally no reason to use the `<img>` with this still... but I guess I'll at least remove my downvote.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Why wouldn't this be compatible? There's nothing cutting-edge or non-standard here. This is a very common way to reduce the logic to simple class membership and to reduce the HTML clutter.

Comment: I didn't even notice you swapped out the `<img>` tag. I imagine you did that because you realized I was right about the `src` hiding the `background-image`. In any event, this is a much better answer than when it first started.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I've been continuously editing this answer for a while. You must have first commented before I got to changing them.

Answer (score 0):

You should could assign a click function at the star and change the corresponding star using 'this'

```
$(".star-pic").click(function (){
  if($(this).attr("src") === "/assets/star-gray.png"){
    $(this).attr("src", "/assets/star-blue.png")
  }else{
    $(this).attr("src", "/assets/star-gray.png")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<img class="star-pic" src="/assets/star-gray.png">
<img class="star-pic" src="/assets/star-gray.png">
<img class="star-pic" src="/assets/star-gray.png">



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var clickedShape = $(this);
  function changeStar(){
    if($(this).attr("src") == "/assets/star-gray.png"){
      $(this).attr("src", "/assets/star-blue.png")
    }
    else{
      $(this).attr("src", "/assets/star-gray.png")
    }
  }

  $(".star-pic").on("click", changeStar)

})

</script>

</body>
</html>
```